# How to loop over Firestore array values in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm stuck at trying to get a cloud function to loop over the values of an array in my Cloud Firestore. I have searched stack overflow but I couldn't find a solution yet.
My Firestore structure looks as follows:

[image]

And my Cloud Function in Jacascript:

```
exports.createdEnv = functions.firestore.document('environments/{environmentName}')
.onCreate(async snapshot => {

const environmentName = snapshot.id;
const days = db.collection(environmentName);
const batch = db.batch();

        ['2020-02-06', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-08'].forEach((day) => {
        const documentReference = days.doc(day);
        batch.set(documentReference, {});

        //this is where I'm stuck
        const dataMachines = snapshot.data().machineNames;
        for (const value in dataMachines) {
        const valueMachine = dataMachines[value];
        console.log(snapshot.get('machineNames')[0]);
        snapshot.get('machineNames').forEach((value) => {

        //I want each value of the array to be set as subcollection below
        const hoursReference = documentReference.collection(value);
        const dataMap = {   '001': '08:00-09:00',
                            '002': '09:00-10:00',
                            '003': '10:00-11:00',
                            '004': '11:00-12:00',
                            '005': '12:00-13:00',
                            '006': '13:00-14:00',
                            '007': '14:00-15:00',
                            '008': '15:00-16:00',
                            '009': '16:00-17:00',
                            '010': '17:00-18:00',
                            '011': '18:00-19:00',
                            '012': '19:00-20:00',
                            '013': '20:00-21:00',
                            '014': '21:00-22:00',
                                                    };
        Object.keys(dataMap).forEach((hour) => {
            batch.set(hoursReference.doc(hour), {
                hour: dataMap[hour],
                reserved: '',
                name: '',
                date: '',
            });
        });

        });

        }

    });

    return batch.commit()
    .then(() => {console.log('ok'); return null })
    .catch((err) => {console.log(err); });
});
```

I have been stuck at this for a while and I feel like I'm missing something or forgetting something. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you exactly want to do. It is a bit difficult to understand. Firstly, why do you do `batch.set(documentReference, {});` You don't pass any (data) value to `set()`.  Secondly, can you give an example of the expected result of your Cloud Function: which documents and collections are created with which content. Thanks!

Comment: Of course! The function creates a new collection with the environmentName as name. In that collection the function sets 3 documents; 2020-02-06, 2020-02-07, 2020-02-08. Then each of these documents should have subcollections with the names of the values from the array. If I substitute ‘value’ in the hoursReference with a simple string then a subcollection is created without problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I have correctly understood your goal, the following should work:

```
//....
const dataMachines = snapshot.data().machineNames;

dataMachines.forEach(machineName => {

    const hoursReference = documentReference.collection(machineName);

    //....

})

//....
```

The call to [`snapshot.data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot?authuser=0#data) returns a JavaScript Object in which the `machineNames` property is an Array. You can check it with  `console.log(Array.isArray(dataMachines));`.

Therefore you just have to use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to get the different values stored in the Array.

---

Side Note: You will find in the [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/3371862) several other possible approaches to loop through a JavaScript Array.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! The link to the other SO answer is also super useful, again thank you so much!